# listview custom sorting with predicate (sortpropery is enum)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting

This code works well

```
 ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);

            if (dataView != null)
            {
                // Specify the new sorting information.
                dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                var description = new SortDescription(propertyName, _sortDirection);
                dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(description);

                dataView.Refresh();               
            }
```

and for exaple string type of propery ir sorts alphabetically , and for enum it sorts in base of enum number , question is i want custom comparison for enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, if you source list implements `IList`, you can cast you collection view source to [`ListCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set [`ListCollectionView.CustomSort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort.aspx) with custom `IComparer` class where you can implement you custom sorting logic

```
ListCollectionView dataView = (ListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource));
dataView.CustomSort = new MyCustomSort();
```